# Find count based on function in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find all count grouped by a unique id, then apply to see how many got crossed a thershold. I want to do it in numpy, I am able to do it using Pandas. Trying to find out on Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

events  = np.array([[  3.,   1., 441., 780.,  30., 262.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1.],
       [  4.,   1., 437., 770.,  30., 274.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1.],
       [  5.,   2., 431., 754.,  31., 286.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  1.]]) 

df=pd.DataFrame(data=events, columns=["uid", "tid", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7","f8"])
```

I want to count how many `f8` column has `-1` for each `tid` column. I am doing it using `df.tid.unique()` and then looping each `row` to check. Now I want to do it is in Numpy, so do I need to use `np.where` function to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `numpy` you can apply this solution:

```
unique, _ = np.unique(events[:,1], return_counts=True)
result = dict(zip(unique, np.zeros(len(unique))))

for i in range(len(events[:,1])):
    if events[i,-1] == -1:
        result[events[i,1]] += 1

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{1.0: 2.0, 2.0: 0.0}
```

Comment: thats lot of code, do you think its faster than converting numpy to pandas. The app totally works just using numpy, but for this logic I used Pandas to write less code. What do you think? the Pandas solution below is bit easy and less number of code.

Comment: @ajayramesh speed or readability... Depends on your needs.

Comment: if its speed ? I must choosing `numpy` right ? for this particular use case ?

Comment: I think using pandas is more readable and also efficient compared to the numpy solution with the loop.

Comment: I am trying to run on `jetson nano` IOT device. I like the readability, my team wants speed.

Answer (score 3):

Let us use `pandas.Series.groupby`

```
df.f8.eq(-1).groupby(df.tid).sum()
Out[67]: 
tid
1.0    2.0
2.0    0.0
Name: f8, dtype: float64
```

Comment: easy one!! do you think its faster than to do in pandas if we have 10K rows or more ?

Comment: @ajayramesh I think so